# "From Review" comment links to wrong review

Tags: bug, review-queues, low-quality-posts, automatic-comments

I came along [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41803970/559745). It looks like it got an auto-comment from the LQP review queue. But when I followed the "From Review" link, I ended up at [this LQP review of another post (deleted)](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/14879579).

I couldn't find the matching LQP review for that answer, but found [its late answer review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/14971720), which was reviewed by the same user that left the comment. And I thought the late answer queue doesn't have any auto-comments?

What happened here?

Comment: *"What happened here?"* That user copied his auto-comment for some reason?

Comment: The post did not have a LQP review at all, Looks like the user has copied the [From Review] part into his canned comments (like what @Tom suggested)